# Using a LU factorization of a matrix to solve for $x$ in a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the $LU$ factorization of $A = \begin{bmatrix}-2&0&1\\2&-4&-3\\0&-16&-10\end{bmatrix}$ and use it to solve the system $\begin{bmatrix}-2&0&1\\2&-4&-3\\0&-16&-10\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\\14\end{bmatrix}$

So I found $L = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&1&0\\0&4&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $U = \begin{bmatrix}-2&0&1\\0&-4&-2\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}$, but how exactly can I use this to solve my system? I know how to solve for the $\vec{x}$ vector by simply using $x = A^{-1}b$ but I'm not sure exactly how to use $LU$ to solve for that vector?

I'm looking to find $x_1, x_2, x_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** Since $A=LU$, we have $A^{-1}=U^{-1}L^{-1}$.

Comment: Is the system not $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$? So yes it is true that $A = LU$ but I am trying to solve for $\vec{x}$ no? So how is this relevant?

Comment: You said you could solve by $x=A^{-1}b$, so apply my hint.

Comment: Your hint has no $\vec{x}$ in it, which is what I'm trying to solve - so i'm confused.

Comment: @Shammy Combining the hint and my comment, you get $x=U^{-1}L^{-1}b$.  Find $U^{-1}$ and $L^{-1}$, then you will be able to find $x$.

Comment: is $(UL)^{-1} \equiv U^{-1}L^{-1}$ or no?

Comment: @Shammy No.  $(LU)^{-1}=U^{-1}L^{-1}$.

Comment: You are correct. I see now that I can find the $LU$ factorization of $A$, I can then see that $Ax = b \implies x = A^{-1}b$ so I can treat $LU$ as $A$ and thus $LUx = b \implies x = (LU)^{-1}b$ !! Thanks @Aweygan

Comment: No problem. In many cases, it will be easier to find $U^{-1}$ and $L^{-1}$ separately, then solve for $x$ with $x=U^{-1}L^{-1}b$.  Especially as the size of the matrix becomes large.